# List index out of range while counting Python

Tags: python, list, counter

I have a little problem - I need to iterate through a list of lists (lines in a file) and count how many times the lines begin with six or seven. It was no problem, but I also need to remove the items which repeat themselves, e.g. if I have this: [6,6,7,7,6], I need to do this out of it: [6,7,6] - it is the number of switches that counts. But somehow the list index is always out of range. Why?
Thank you!

```
def number_of_switches(list):
    counter = []
    for element in li: 
        if int(element[0]) == 6 or int(element[0]) == 7: counter.append(element[0])
        else: pass
    i = 0   
    for i in (0, len(counter)):
    if counter[i] == counter[i+1]: counter.remove(counter[i+1])
    print 'number of switches is', len(counter)-1 #the first number doesn't count as switch, hence '-1'
```

Comment: `for i in (0, len(counter)):` should it be `for i in range(len(counter)):` ?

Comment: no, in this case it says "TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable"

Answer (score 2):

`for i in (0, len(counter))` only iterates over *two* elements: 0, and the length of `counter`. It does *not* count up from 0 to the length. For that you need range:

```
for i in range(len(counter))
```

However, you should not do that either. Think about what happens each time you remove an element: the list is now one shorter, but you are iterating until the end of the original list. So you will quickly get an IndexError. You need to append the non-matching elements to a *new* list, rather than removing from the current one.

Comment: I tried to do this 
    for i in range(len(counter)):
        if counter[i] != counter[i+1]: new.append(counter[i])
which creates the list with only non-repeated elements, but yet again, I get this list index out of range error and cannot see why. If I do i in range(len(counter)-1), it works, but doesn't compare the last element. I just can't see why the len(counter) wouldn't work :(

Comment: Because on the last iteration, i == len(counter). So i+1 is going to be past the end of the list.

Comment: but how can I fix that if range(len(counter)-1) doesn't compare the very last one? is there a solution for this?

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. What do you want to compare the last one to? Iterating until len - 1 will compare the second last to the last, which must be what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing `for i in range(len(counter)):` and also `if counter[i] == counter[i+1]:` will give an error in this range. You need to handle the end case.

This might be a better solution:

```
def number_of_switches(list):
    counter = []
    prev = li[0]
    for element in range(1, len(li)): 
        if int(li[element][0]) != prev:
            count.append(int(li[element][0]))
    print 'number of switches is', len(counter)-1 #the first number doesn't count as switch, hence '-1'
```

Comment: but I need to compare it with the next object in the list, how else could I do it?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
for i in (0, len(counter)):
```

That means for in those two values: 0 and len(counter) and, len(counter) is the index out of range.
I think you meant:

```
for i in range(0, len(counter)):
```